# How to retrieve rendered padding value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a element with `padding-right: 0.25em;` and `font-size: 2.75em;`, this element is inside its parent node. the parent node has this style : `font-size: 20px`.

So the actual padding of the element is controlled by font size of the parent node right?

I may change my parent node font size to have different padding right value, How can I dynamically retrieve the **real rendered** value of the new padding-right?

I tried :

```
$('.word').innerWidth() - $('.word').width()
```

But this bring only the fixed value!!! in my case 12..

Comment: the, what?..... .

Comment: Haha... the fixed value...

Comment: could you post more code, full css and full html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) as following:

```
let para = document.querySelector('.word');
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(para);

let mypadding = compStyles.getPropertyValue('padding-right');
```

Comment: @SaraRee ... just in order to have it mentioned ... there is also the still experimental technology of [`Element.computedStyleMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap) Web-API.